# Surface Tension - Peculiar behavior of Water Drop and Mercury Drop inside a Conical Tube

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, liquid-state

When a water drop and a mercury drop are taken into two different but same kind of conical tubes, the water drop on its own tends to move towards the narrower end and the mercury drop tends to move towards the wider end, why? Why does this happen? How do we explain this phenomenon?

Following is a question based on the same phenomenon along with the right answer, for the greater understanding of the question.

Kindly help.

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting phenomenon! But the part having the question 21 is classified here as homework question and is prone to be closed. So make sure to read these posts: [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583); For this question, I'd advise you to edit out the HW part and add some more details on what and why do you think might happen here?

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, I am asking for the concept and I believe it is totally a conceptual question. Just because I posted a question based on it, shouldn't make it a homework like question, I believe.

Comment: I have edited the question a bit, on your suggestion.

Comment: Keywords: surface tension, wettability.